# Pod cannot reach its own IP on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am migrating from aws to gke but somewhy I cannot reach my own ip

```
cescoferraro@g7: ~/go/src/github.com/cescoferraro/mongo-k8s-sidecar on develop [!]
$ k exec -it mongo-0 -c mongo bash
root@mongo-0:/# curl 10.32.2.70:27017^C
root@mongo-0:/# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:58:0a:20:02:46  
          inet addr:10.32.2.70  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4820:f6ff:fe60:a655/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1460  Metric:1
          RX packets:13433 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:65150095 (65.1 MB)  TX bytes:4359632 (4.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:13924 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13924 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2303174 (2.3 MB)  TX bytes:2303174 (2.3 MB)

root@mongo-0:/# curl 10.32.2.70:27017
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.32.2.70 port 27017: Connection refused
root@mongo-0:/# curl 127.0.0.1:27017
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
root@mongo-0:/# curl 10.35.251.6 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" id="boss">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="xMFg9XEP67BGHFJRngurli0aSWzW5axaha2DYHhBaag">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=5">
...
```

the k8s configuration

```
## Generate a key
# openssl rand -base64 741 > mongodb-keyfile
## Create k8s secrets
# kubectl create secret generic mongo-key --from-file=mongodb-keyfile
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - >
            if [ -f /data/db/admin-user.lock ]; then
              mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --setParameter authenticationMechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-1;
            else
              mongod --auth;
            fi;
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - >
                  if [ ! -f /data/db/admin-user.lock ]; then
                    sleep 5;
                    touch /data/db/admin-user.lock
                    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "mongo-0" ]; then
                      mongo --eval 'db = db.getSiblingDB("admin"); db.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "pass", roles: [{ role: "root", db: "admin" }]});';
                    fi;
                    mongod --shutdown;
                  fi;
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
        - name: mongo-sidecar
          image: onnidev/mongosidecar
          env:
            - name: MONGO_SIDECAR_POD_LABELS
              value: "role=mongo,environment=test"
            - name: MONGODB_USERNAME
              value: admin
            - name: MONGODB_PASSWORD
              value: pass 
            - name: MONGODB_DATABASE
              value: admin
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-persistent-storage
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "fast"
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 4Gi
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete. I don't think anyone’s going to be able to debug this problem for you. Please consider adding your depoyment/pod manifest to show how your pod gets deployed.

Comment: It is far more likely that you don't have `mongod` set to listen on all interfaces, as their default changed in 3.6: https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp

Comment: @AhmetB-Google here it is!

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel you nailed it! thanks! somewhy I binding to 0.0.0.0 did not cut it.

Comment: I had to bind to the loopback and the container eth0 ip before I could get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to implement a statefulset mongo deploy on GKE based off this [document](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-mongodb-statefulset/index.html) 
But unfortunately the example is outdated.
Matthew nailed the issue on the comments above pointing that mongo states the following [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp)

> Starting in MongoDB 3.6, mongos or mongod bind to localhost by default.

so the fix was to boot the server using the bind_ip flag like

```
mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1,$(hostname -I) --setParameter authenticationMechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-1
```

The mongo 3.6 deprecates the way the `cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar` project authenticates using username and password, so I made a [PR](https://github.com/cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar/pull/95) in order to fix it and built my own containerized version living at `onnidev/mongosidecar`

```
## Generate a key
# openssl rand -base64 741 > mongodb-keyfile
## Create k8s secrets
# kubectl create secret generic mongo-key --from-file=mongodb-keyfile
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    role: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - >
            if [ -f /data/db/admin-user.lock ]; then
              export IP=$(hostname -I) 
              mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1,$IP --setParameter authenticationMechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-1;
            else
              mongod --auth;
            fi;
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - >
                  if [ ! -f /data/db/admin-user.lock ]; then
                    sleep 5;
                    touch /data/db/admin-user.lock
                    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "mongo-0" ]; then
                      mongo --eval 'db = db.getSiblingDB("admin"); db.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "pass", roles: [{ role: "root", db: "admin" }]});';
                    fi;
                    mongod --shutdown;
                  fi;
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
        - name: mongo-sidecar
          image: onnidev/mongosidecar
          env:
            - name: MONGO_SIDECAR_POD_LABELS
              value: "role=mongo,environment=test"
            - name: MONGODB_USERNAME
              value: admin
            - name: MONGODB_PASSWORD
              value: pass 
            - name: MONGODB_DATABASE
              value: admin
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-persistent-storage
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "fast"
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 4Gi
```